# Repeat effect with timing

Tags: jquery, effects

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.HighlightedTr').delay(1000).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);        
});`
```

Works good but once.. Is it possible to repeat this with some delay? like every seconds or every 5 seconds?

Txs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the setInterval function.

```
var interval = setInterval(code, 4000);
```

This will execute code **every** 4000 milliseconds.

Code could also be an anonymous function.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        ....
    }, 4000);
```

`setTimeout` instead executes your code just **once**, after some time.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        ...
    }, 4000);
```

You code will be called after 4000 milliseconds.

Finally, you can cancel these timers with `clearTimeout(interval)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('.HighlightedTr').delay(1000).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);        
    }, 5000);
});
```

repeats it evers 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function(){
          $('.HighlightedTr').delay(1000).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
    }, 5000);
});
```